# Jbutton acionando uma tecla

Tags: java

É possível "simular" o apertar de uma tecla de uma teclado ao clique de um Jbutton dentro de outro programa?
Quero fazer isso pois estou mexendo com versões antigas do AMCap .

Comment: Depende, adicione o código onde você quer fazer isso para que possa ser verificado se é possivel.

Comment: Se você tem acesso ao código do "outro programa" você pode colocar ele próprio para simular o apertar da tecla, não?